# Removing duplicate elements from a Python list containing unhashable elements while preserving order?

Tags: python

I have a datastructure like this:

```
[
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2')],
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2')],
[('A', '4'), ('C', '5')]
]
```

And I want to obtain this:

```
[
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2')],
[('A', '4'), ('C', '5')]
]
```

Is there a good way of doing this while preserving order as shown?

Commands for copy-pasting:

```
sample = []
sample.append([('A', '1'), ('B', '2')])
sample.append([('A', '1'), ('B', '2')])
sample.append([('A', '4'), ('C', '5')])
```

Comment: Are the duplicates always adjacent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a somewhat famous question which was well answered by a famous Pythonista long ago:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52560-remove-duplicates-from-a-sequence/

If you can assume equal records are adjacent, there is a recipe in the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby, imap

def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return imap(next, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

If you can only assume orderable elements, here a variant using the bisect module.  Given *n* inputs with *r* unique values, its search step costs O(n log r).  If a new unique value is found, it is inserted in the *seen* list for a cost of O(r * r).

```
from bisect import bisect_left, insort

def dedup(seq):
    'Remove duplicates. Preserve order first seen.  Assume orderable, but not hashable elements'
    result = []
    seen = []
    for x in seq:
        i = bisect_left(seen, x)
        if i == len(seen) or seen[i] != x:
            seen.insert(i, x)
            result.append(x)
    return result
```

Comment: The only order-preserving recipe by Tim Peters is brute force.  The sorting recipe can be modified to keep O(n log n) performance while preserving the order, though.

Comment: The order-preserving variants are by Alex Martelli and are listed below Tim's code in the comments.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the variants by Alex Martelli all assume hasability.

Comment: I thought there was a non-hashable, non-brute force variant in there somewhere and that it made it into the Python Cookbook.  In case it isn't there, I've editted the answer above to show how it could be done using bisect (assumes orderability, but not hashability).

Comment: I think your algorithm is O(n*n) due to `seen.insert(i, x)`. (This is insertion sort.)

Comment: That's true in the worst case where every input is unique.  The insertion step only happens when a new, unique value is encountered.  When there are many duplicates, the insertions is frequently skipped.  dedup('GATTACAACGTCAT') does four insertions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an order-preserving variant of the sort/unique idiom.  This will give you O(n log n) performance, provided your items are at least sortable.

```
def unique(a):
    indices = sorted(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)
    indices = set(next(it) for k, it in 
                  itertools.groupby(indices, key=a.__getitem__))
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i in indices]
```

Example (with hashable items for simplicity):

```
>>> a = ['F', 'J', 'B', 'F', 'V', 'A', 'E', 'U', 'B', 'U', 'Z', 'K']
>>> unique(a)
['F', 'J', 'B', 'V', 'A', 'E', 'U', 'Z', 'K']
```